# Gulp Stream completion with promises

Tags: node.js, gulp, node-streams

I am trying to read a file in, do a transform that is promise based and push the results through the stream. Here is the example code.

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const gutil = require('gulp-util')
const through2 = require('through2')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (filePath, options) => {

    return gulp.src(filePath)
    .pipe(through2.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {
        const result = file.contents.toString(enc)
        Promise.resolve(result)
        .then( result => {
            cb(null, result)
        })
        .catch(() => {})

    }))

}
```

For some reason when the promise resolves and I try to call the callback I get nothing downstream and the stream never completes.

I have also tried this.push(result) and then call the callback but still the same issue. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

So after some searching through other gulp util repos I see that this is how to resolve the callback properly:

```
return gulp.src(filePath)
 .pipe(through2.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {
    const result = file.contents.toString(enc)
    Promise.resolve(result)
    .then( result => {
        file.contents = new Buffer(result);
        this.push(file)
        cb()
    })
    .catch(() => {})

}))
```